# get IP address of node app running in docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, docker, request

I have a node express app running in a Docker container and through the app i'm trying to log the IP address of the incoming request. Since i'm running everything behind a firewall i used something like this "req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress" but it logs the same IP address each time irrespective of the request origin. i.e. i always see the same IP even when it is made from different IP's.

Is there an elegant way to log the IP address of the node app running in a docker container. Will using this package help https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip

If not please suggest a way to capture the IP address.

Comment: do you any reverse proxy which sets the x-forwarded-for for you ? A firewall does not matter in this case. A NAT or a misconfigured RP does.

Comment: Not sure.. Is there a place where i can check that

Comment: this helps ? https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/15086 I m not docker user yet.

Comment: It was mentioned as "disable the userland proxy" would be the fix.. I'm a newbie with Docker myself so trying to figure out some syntax or any npm package with which i can log the incoming request's IP.

Comment: docker problem. then to get the real client ip, this is correct `req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress`

Comment: Yeah, when i use that i see the same IP being logged again and again. Even though a request originates from a different IP i see the same IP number in all of them.

Comment: Can some one help me out with this? i'm kind of still stuck with this one.

Comment: So i tried "request-ip", "forwarded-for" packages but still no luck, i get an IP in the logs but that's not my real IP.

Comment: I have the same issue!! :S :S

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but this might still help.

What worked for me was a combination of my Express container and NGINX running as a reverse proxy on the host machine.

For the NGINX, I added the following settings:

```
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9461;               # <-- put the exposed port of the Docker Express container
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

With the above, once I access my Express container (via my specified NGINX `server_name`), the IP of the request will be stored in `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` :

```
    console.log("IP of this request is:", req.headers['x-forwarded-for']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');

let hostname = 'localhost';
exec("ip route | awk '/default/ {print $3}'", (error, stdout) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error('cannot get outer ip address for wrapper service', error);
    } else {
        hostname = stdout.replace(/\n/, '');
    }
});
```

After that, in `hostname` variable contains the host ip.